# How to record both sides in WhatsApp voice call recording?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, call-recording

I recorded an interview over my last WhatsApp audio call. But when I played back, only my voice was recorded. Is there any way I can get the voice call record? I can't find the call folder in my WhatsApp files. I have a Redmi note 8.

Comment: How was it recorded? As far as I know (I might be wrong), it is not possible to record calls via WhatsApp itself. Did you use a third-party app to do it?